# Json object img url problem when encode from PHP and andriod studio

Tags: php, json

My json php encoded with a slash problem. When php encoded a web image address it shows slashes instead of normal slashes. This is what it shows when json php encoded the url of an image address.

```
{"posts":[{"id":"326","img_url":"http:\ / \ /doman name.com\ /folder\ /images\ /name - Copy.jpg"},{"id":"325","img_url":"http:\ / \ /doman name.com\ /folder\/images\ /d.jpg"}]}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the word "dashes"?

Comment: like php encoded the forward dashes and backward dashes all into the web url of the image location.

Comment: You mean `slashes`? And it is totally correct json. `dash` is `-`.

Comment: oops..yes slashes. Thank you.

Comment: the slashes as in this symbol    / \

Comment: And what's the problem with them? Backslash __escapes__ forward slash.

Comment: How does your PHP create this JSON?

Comment: ok i used strip slashes. Thanks..and thanks for editing my question.

Comment: ok still having problem on android part.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem after gotten some help from you guys about escape slashes. Thank you.